# How many lattice paths with step S and W are there that begin at (0,0), end at (-12,-12)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

How many lattice paths with step $S$ and $W$ are there that begin at $(0,0)$, end at $(-12,-12)$ and do not go through any of the points $(-1,-4), \space (-5,-3), \space (-9,-11)$?

I'm unsure of how to approach this question. Any hint would be good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_1$ = the set of paths going through (-1,-4), $c_2$ = the set of paths going through (-5,-3), etc.

Then, use the inclusion-exclusion principle to solve for N($c_1'c_2'c_3'$).

$N$ = $24\choose 12$.

$N(c_1)$ = $5\choose 4$$19\choose 11$ etc.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed a hint!